# The commutator of Holomorph of generalized quaternion is abelian?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, derived-subgroup, holomorph

Let $Q_{2^{n}} = \langle x, y | x^{2^{n-1}}=y^4 = 1, x^{2^{n-2}}=y^2, y^{-1}xy = x^{-1} \rangle$ - generalized quaternion group of order $2^{n}$.

$\operatorname{Hol}(Q_{2^{n}})$ - [Holomorph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorph_(mathematics)) of this group

Let $G = [ \operatorname{Hol}(Q_{2^{n+1}}), \operatorname{Hol}(Q_{2^{n}})]$ - [commutator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator_subgroup) of $\operatorname{Hol}(Q_{2^{n+1}})$

I'm wondering whether $G$ is abelian.

Using the SAGE, I checked that this is true for $n = 3 ... 9$.

Some auxiliary facts:

1. $${\rm Aut}(Q_{2^n}) \cong  \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} : a \in \mathbb{Z}^*_{2^{n-1}}, b\in \mathbb{Z}_{2^{n-1}} \right\} \cong AGL(\mathbb{Z}_{2^{n-1}}, 1)$$
   such that for $\varphi \in {\rm Aut}(Q_{2^n})$
   $$\varphi (x) = x^a, \varphi (y) = x^by$$
2. $[Q_{2^n}, Q_{2^n}] = \langle x^2 \rangle$
3. $[{\rm Aut}(Q_{2^n}), {\rm Aut}(Q_{2^n})] = \left\{ \varphi : \varphi(x) = x, \varphi (y) = x^by,\space b\in 2\mathbb{Z}_{2^{n-1}}\right\}$

Comment: A vote to close, a downvote, and no explanation of why, all in ten minuts — on the first question of someone who's been around for a week. Amazing.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I'm not responsible for the down- or close vote, but the first edit shortly after the question was posted. I think it is an interesting question for itself, but to avoid downvotes, you should provide context: Why are you asking the question and how did it arise? What have you tried to solve it and what ideas did you have? What did work and what did not? (This makes it easier for us to help you.)

Comment: For this question in particular, you could for example tell us, where exactly Sage has shown this or link a definition of the holomorph (for example Wikipedia or nLab) for those who need to review it again. You can always edit your question and sometimes a downvote will then disappear. If you have questions, I'm happy to help.

Comment: While the question could be improved, it is fundamentally a reasonable question, and I find it irritating  when people who have no idea how to solve the problem and may not even understand it vote to close. Why not just ignore the question if you don't understand it? You could probably ask this question on MathOverflow and it would get more respect there.

Comment: But the presentation of $Q_{2^{n+1}}$ is wrong. You need the extra relation $y^{-1}xy=x^{-1}$. Also the holomorph is nonabelian when $n=2$, but that's an exception because $Q_8$ has an automorphism of order $3$.

Comment: @SamuelAdrianAntz ,thanks for your remarks

Comment: @DerekHolt, already fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

- $\forall \varphi \in {\rm Aut}(Q_{2^n}), \forall g \in Q_{2^n} \;\; \varphi (g) g^{-1} \in \langle x \rangle$.
- $\forall \tau \in [{\rm Aut}(Q_{2^n}), {\rm Aut}(Q_{2^n})] \;\; x^{\tau} = x$. ($x^{\tau} = \tau (x)$)
- $[{\rm Aut}(Q_{2^n}), {\rm Aut}(Q_{2^n})]$ and $[Q_{2^n},Q_{2^n}]$ are abelian.

Consider two elements from the Holomorph $\varphi g, \phi h\in {\rm Hol}(Q_{2^n})$. Note that $\varphi g \cdot \phi h = \varphi \phi g^{\phi}h$ and $(\varphi g)^{-1} = \varphi^{-1} (g^{-1})^{\varphi^{-1}}$.

As anyone can see, $[\varphi g, \phi h] = [\varphi, \phi] \cdot (g^{\phi} h g^{-1} (h^{-1})^{\varphi})^{\varphi^{-1} \phi^{-1}} = [\varphi, \phi] \cdot \alpha$.
$$\alpha = (g^{\phi} h g^{-1} (h^{-1})^{\varphi})^{\varphi^{-1} \phi^{-1}} = (g^{\phi}g^{-1} [g,h] h (h^{-1})^{\varphi})^{\varphi^{-1} \phi^{-1}}$$
As above, $g^{\phi}g^{-1}$,  $h (h^{-1})^{\varphi}$ $\in \langle x \rangle$ and $[g,h]\in \langle x^2 \rangle \subset \langle x \rangle$, then $\alpha \in \langle x \rangle$, because $\varphi^{-1} \phi^{-1}$ - automorphism.

In that way, for some elements $\tau \alpha, \sigma \beta \in [{\rm Hol}(Q_{2^n}),{\rm Hol}(Q_{2^n})]$ we have that $\beta^{\tau} = \beta$ and $\alpha^{\sigma} = \alpha$.

Then
$$\tau \alpha \cdot \sigma \beta = \tau \sigma \alpha^{\sigma} \beta = \tau \sigma \alpha \beta = \sigma \tau \beta \alpha = \sigma \tau \beta^{\tau} \alpha = \sigma \beta \cdot \tau \alpha,$$
e.g. $[{\rm Hol}(Q_{2^n}),{\rm Hol}(Q_{2^n})]$ is abelian.